# Servlet receives OPTIONS instead of GET requests from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, http, servlets, fullcalendar

All I want to achieve is to implement a servlet providing a json feed for my fullcalendar application. When I inspect http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar/examples/json.html with Bugzilla, I see that GET-requests are sent to receive the json feed.

However, when I use this example within my scenario, fullcalendar seems to send OPTIONS-requests. The only difference is that I replaced "events: "json-events.php" with "http://localhost:8080/CalendarServletTest/HelloWorldServlet" (the url of my servlet).
What do I miss? Or is this really a bug?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery may indeed do this when it needs to fire a **crossdomain** XMLHttpRequest while the return `dataType` is not [`jsonp`](http://www.insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html). This is behaviour by design and it may be dependent on the security configuration of the webbrowser used. The HTTP [`OPTIONS`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.2) request should just return an [`Allow`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.7) header with a list of request methods which are allowed to be used on the particular URL so that jQuery could then continue accordingly.

This should actually not cause a technical problem, but if you don't want to let it fire an `OPTIONS` request, then you need to let the servlet run in the same domain, or to implement [`doOptions()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doOptions%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) accordingly (the [`HttpServlet`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) however does its task properly by default, so this should actually not form a technical problem), or to change the `dataType` to [`jsonp`](http://www.insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html) in Fullcalendar's source (and if necessary report it to the Fullcalendar guys as well).